# Taking $\lim$ out of metric $d$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ is metric space. Let $d(y_n,z_n)\to r$. And let $(y_{m_k})$ and $(z_{m_k})$ be subsequences of $(y_n)$ and $(z_n)$ respectively, with $(y_{m_k})\to y\in X$ and $(z_{m_k})\to z\in X$. (Yes, the indices of subsequences are same.)

> How to show that $$d(y,z)=d(\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} y_{m_k},\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} z_{m_k})=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}d(y_{m_k},z_{m_k})=r?$$

I am having trouble deriving second of equality above (obviously).

I went line this: $d(\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} y_{m_k},z)=\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}d(y_{m_k},z)$ by continuity of $x\to d(x,a)$ for fixed $a$. But But I can't take out lim for both the $x$ and $y$ simultaneously.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/528220/42969: A metric is *continuous* (in both arguments).

Comment: Or this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2525328/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the triangle inequality, $$d(y_{m_k},z_{m_k}) \leq d(y_{m_k},y) + d(y,z) +d(z,z_{m_k})\tag{1}$$ and also
$$d(y,z) \leq d(y, y_{m_k}) + d(y_{m_k},z_{m_k}) +d(z_{m_k},z)\tag{2}$$
Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ gives
$$|d(y,z)-d(y_{m_k},z_{m_k})|\leq d(y, y_{m_k}) +d(z_{m_k},z)$$
Now, the right-hand side converges to zero, by assumptions.